# Load specific rows using expressions

Tags: sql, qlikview

How do I load specific rows using expressions in qlikview? For example, I have 2 columns in my excel which are LEVEL1 and LEVEL2. I want to load the rows as Level4 rows.

Currently im doing something likw the code below to get 16.29, 16.31 and 16.30 from LEVEL2 and the rest of LEVEL1 to be loaded as LEVEL4.

IF(LEVEL2 = '16.29', LEVEL2, IF(LEVEL2 = '16.31', LEVEL2, IF(LEVEL2 = '16.30'), LEVEL2, LEVEL1))) AS LEVEL4,

Is there a simpler way to do this? I need a simpler way because if i want to load more LEVEL2 specific rows, it will get complicated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the [match](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/match.htm) function:

```
if(match(LEVEL2,16.29,16.31,16.30),LEVEL2,LEVEL1) as LEVEL4
```